# how to make sure that a batch of requests are ready

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop, callback

I need to get via API prices per dates for the following 12 months.

One requirement is that requests cant be over 2 months. So I need to split this in 6 requests.

So I get from current date to +1 month and I iterate 5 times more to get the 10 remaining months, like so:

```
const getPeriod = (dateIn, dateOut) => {
  axios
    .post(
      Utils.apiUrl,
      {
        hotelCodes: Utils.hotelId.split(','),
        dateIn: dateIn, 
        dateOut: dateOut, 
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      const calendarPrices = response.data.CalendarPrices
      var now = new Date()
      for (let d = 0; d < calendarPrices.length; d++) {
        const date = new Date(calendarPrices[d].Date)
        date.setHours(12, now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()) 
        calendarPrices[d].dateObj = date
      }
      if (Utils.calendarPrices) {
        Utils.calendarPrices = Utils.calendarPrices.concat(calendarPrices)
      } else {
        Utils.calendarPrices = calendarPrices
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}

const getNextMonths = () => {
  for (let r = 1; r <= requestsToMake; r++) {
    let dateIn = new Date()
    dateIn.setMonth(dateIn.getMonth() + 2 * r)
    const monthIn =
      (dateIn.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') +
      (parseInt(dateIn.getMonth(), 10) + 1)

    let dateOut = new Date()
    dateOut.setMonth(dateOut.getMonth() + 1 + 2 * r)
    const monthOut =
      (dateOut.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') +
      (parseInt(dateOut.getMonth(), 10) + 1)
    const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(
      dateOut.getFullYear(),
      dateOut.getMonth() + 1,
      0
    )

    getPeriod(
      `${dateIn.getFullYear()}-${monthIn}-01`,
      `${dateOut.getFullYear()}-${monthOut}-${lastDayOfMonth.getDate()}`
    )

  }
}



// get current month and the next one  
  axios
  .post(
    Utils.apiUrl,
    {
      hotelCodes: Utils.hotelId.split(','),
      dateIn: `${dateIn.getFullYear()}-${
        (dateIn.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' : '') +
        parseInt(dateIn.getMonth() + 1, 10)
      }-${(dateIn.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + dateIn.getDate()}`,
      dateOut: `${dateOut.getFullYear()}-${
        (dateOut.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' : '') +
        parseInt(dateOut.getMonth() + 1, 10)
      }-${
        (lastDayOfMonth.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') +
        lastDayOfMonth.getDate()
      }`,
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    const calendarPrices = response.data.CalendarPrices
    var now = new Date()
    for (let d = 0; d < calendarPrices.length; d++) {
      const date = new Date(calendarPrices[d].Date)
      date.setHours(12, now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()) 
      calendarPrices[d].dateObj = date
    }

    if (Utils.calendarPrices) {
      Utils.calendarPrices = Utils.calendarPrices.concat(
        calendarPrices
      )
    } else {
      Utils.calendarPrices = calendarPrices
    }

   
    datepicker = new HotelDatepicker(input, options)
    // get 10 more months
    getNextMonths()
  })
```

The problem i'm having is that those are async calls when the calendar is ready only the first request is complete

How can i make sure all dates have been recived before I init the calendar?

I'm thinking in making a recursive function but i don't know how to handle the callbacks..

Comment: I have done something similiar, where a need to do batchs of requests. The solution was to use promisse.all(https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). I created a array of promises and then used promise.all to resolve all of then together, and only got the response when all promise get resolved. Maybe this can help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I see that there is  axios's promise.all. I'll see if I can make it work ^^